# how to use grep command in .log file if it is not empty

Tags: linux, bash

i have a log file. When the log file is not empty then i should grep command for policy and work flow. i have tried this code, but how can I initialize the log file and use this command?

```
cmd=`grep -c "POLICY" file`


if [[ $(grep -c "POLICY" file) -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo "POLICY are present"
else
    echo "POLICY not present"
fi
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The code you posted works, but is clumsy and unidiomatic. If you are trying to use `cmd` as a variable, don't; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -q`. It will return 0 (success) if any match is found, otherwise (even if the files does not exist) it will return 1 (failure).

```
if grep -q POLICY file; then
    echo "POLICY are present"
else
    echo "POLICY not present"
fi
```